# Cannot apply 50% discount to one page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Hi fellow StackOverflow guys,

First of all this is on Magento 1.7.0.2.

I have 3 categories. All of them work the the same products. I have 3 different CMS pages which work with their own category. So, for example, the CMS Homepage displays all products from category 6. This all works find and dandy...

**The Problem:**

I created another page which is a duplicate of homepage. This page displays all the products shown on homepage except that each product should be 50% off.

When I apply a "Catalog Price Rule" for the discount category id it applies it to ALL the categories in error. I only want the 50% to be applied to the discount page...

**Here is the CMS Page that displays the 50% off page:**

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="16" template="catalog/product/list_home.phtml"}}
```

**Screenshot of the Category Page:**
http://postimage.org/image/ux7rfdl4b/

**Screenshot of the Promotions->Catalog Price Rules Page:**
http://postimage.org/image/4avaqegx7/

I tried looking for solutions prior to posting this and cannot come up with anything useful. The only other option I can think of is duplicate each product and give it a different SKU number and with a 50% off price. I hope it doesn't come to that though...

Best Regards,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the rule works properly. But it applies the discount to PRODUCTS in categories, not the CATEGORIES themselves. Your products that are in HomePage are ALSO in HomePage_Discounted (at least 9/10 of them), so they get a discount no matter where you see them.

The quickest way would be to duplicate the HomePage products and assign the duplicates to the HomePage_Discounted category. The original ones have to stay only in HomePage category. Then, be sure to enter the discount rule and click "Save and Apply" button (without making any changes to the rule), so the discounted products are computed again.

Another way would be to create a discount code, show it on the 50% discount CMS page and just use it to create discounts (not exactly what you asked for, but the effect is the same - only users that visit this page get the discount).

Let me know if any of those options help you. If not, we can search for another solution.

Comment: Thanks Bartosz. I wasn't aware I even got replies to my posted thread (thought I was subscribed) but I went with duplicating the products and putting them in the HomePage_Discounted category which was my alternative option to begin with but was very determined to get it working the other way. Now I know that if a product is in a few different categories and I say apply price rule to one category it is in it will apply to the other ones as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration should work properly.

Verify your catalog price rule configuration:

```
If ALL these conditions are TRUE:
Category is 16
```

Then, make sure you SAVE AND APPLY the rule. No 'Apply' no change on the frontend.

Clear your Caches and if possible (small catalog) you can reindex your Product Price Rules Index (not usually required, its happened to before though)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Robert. This was done on a dev server and I have caching disabled. I do reindex and compile sometimes even though it is not required. Never know... sometimes it will fix things. Anyway, seems to be functioning as desired now.